# Navbar not formatting correctly in BootStrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have used some BootStrap in my html but for some reason my name is not being lined up with the other elements when I resize or make it full screen.  I am using the `nav navbar`. It's a basic example of using the `nav navbar` so it shouldn't be a big problem but I am having trouble looking for the error in my code.

Code below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> BootStrap NavBar</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">

    </head>
    <body>

    <nav class = "navbar navbar-default"> 
        <div class = "container">
     <div class = "navbar-header"
        <a href="#" class = "navbar-brand" > Mohamed</a>
    </div>

    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav"> 
    <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Contacts </a></li>

    </ul>


    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li> <a href="#"> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Login </a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </nav> 





    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Side note, you have a typo in your code. Missing a closing `>` in `<div class = "navbar-header"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed closing tag char in the line bellow

```
<div class = "navbar-header">
```